# Trying to convert this database to csv then connecting and updating a database table

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I am trying to convert the MNC/MCC data to csv so that it can be uploaded to a mysql database through the connector. Any help appreciated.

```
import re
import urllib2
import csv
import mysql.connector

print("MCC,MCC (int),MNC,MNC (int),ISO,Country,Country Code,Network")
td_re = re.compile('<td>([^<]*)</td>'*6)

html = urllib2.urlopen('http://mcc-mnc.com/').read()

tbody_start = False
for line in html.split('\n'):
    if '<tbody>' in line:
        tbody_start = True
    elif '</tbody>' in line:
        break
    elif tbody_start:
        td_search = td_re.search(line)
        csv_line = ''
        for n in range(1, 7):
            group = td_search.group(n).strip().replace(',', '')
            csv_line += group
            if n == 1:
                csv_line += ',' + str(int(group, 16))
            elif n == 2:
                if len(group) == 2:
                    mnc_int = int(group + 'f', 16)
                elif group != 'n/a':
                    mnc_int = int(group, 16)
                csv_line += ',' + str(mnc_int)
            if n != 6:
                csv_line += ','
        print csv_line

csv_data = csv_line
for row in csv_data:
    with open('test_csv.csv','w') as f: # open the file, if it exists overwrite it, if it doesn't create it.
        for dataLine in csv_line: # iterate through all the data
            f.write(dataLine)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
    user='root',
    passwd='xxxxxx',
    db='tester')


mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (MCC,MCC_int, MNC, MNC_int, ISO, Country, Country_Code, Network) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
val = [ csv_data ]
mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
mydb.commit()

print(mydb.rowcount, "record(s) affected")
```

I am presented to with this error 
"Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: You have a typo in **VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s%s,%s,)** it should be **VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)**

Comment: I have noticed and changed that (right after posting) however I am still presented with the same error.

Comment: What do you have in csv_data??

Comment: CSV_data would be the result of urllib reading the link of the current MNC/MCC database for telecommunications, and the code under converts it to a proper csv format.

Comment: Have you tried doing VALUES (%s)??

Comment: I just tried, I am still getting the same ProgrammingError.